# iOS - how to draw a line of custom shapes

Tags: ios, swift

I am porting my android app over to iOS using Swift.

With android, I am able to draw a line made up of a series of custom shapes, defined as path objects, by using the `PathDashPathEffect` object.

```
    m_StampPath = new Path();
    m_StampPath.moveTo(...);
    m_StampPath.cubicTo(...);
    m_StampPath.cubicTo(...);
    ...
    m_StampPath.close();
    
    m_WavyLine = new PathDashPathEffect(m_StampPath, fStampOffset, 0.0f, PathDashPathEffect.Style.MORPH);

    // this is a Paint object
    pt.setPathEffect(m_WavyLine);
    pt.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    LinePath = new Path();
    LinePath.moveTo(...);
    LinePath.lineTo(...);

    canvas.drawPath(LinePath, pt);
```

How can I achieve the same thing by using swift in iOS ?

I have not found anything as yet, but perhaps I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Do you want to freehand draw lines or draw something defind from code?

Comment: `UIBezierPath` ?

Comment: To answer the first question, no, this is not a freehand line, but rather a glissando line in a music score.  UIBezierPath ? - perhaps, but I have not seen how to use this as yet - perhaps an example ?

Comment: Maybe you could start from an example such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946432/how-to-create-dashed-line-with-arrow-in-swift-4-with-the-help-bezier-path

Comment: Had a look and saw that it draws a 'simple' dashed line and adds a UIBezierPath object at the end for the arrow head. What I need to do is to create a UIBezierPath object and have it repeated along and at the place of the line, rotating as necessary according to the angle of the line.